# What is the relation between structure groups or transition functions of two isomorphic vector bundles?

Tags: vector-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry, line-bundles

Vector bundle $S=\Lambda^{\bullet}T^*M \otimes |\det TM|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is called an spinor bundle for the bundle $TM\oplus T^*M$.
it is an associated bundle to a $Spin(n,n)$-principal bundle where the fibers in this association is the spin representation which here is 
$$\rho:Spin(n,n)\to \operatorname{End}(\Lambda^{\bullet}T^*M)$$
I don't know why the following statement is true.

Here Since $|\det TM|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle, we see that there is always a choice of spin
structure such that the spin bundle is (non-canonically) isomorphic to the exterior algebra $\Lambda^{\bullet} T^*M$.

Here I'm looking forward to figure this out: that it seems to be a fact that occurs to be always true about vector bundles. I think it's of no importance what an spinor bundle is here and this fact that I don't seem to find it happens to be true in general for any vector bundle. Something about how transition functions are involved in this isomorphism?

If I'm completely miss leaded here a hint will be a lot appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reference you could point us to?  I haven't seen these statements before.  Why is $| \det TM |^{1/2}$ trivial?  I also am interested in the idea of using $\Lambda^* T^*M$ as a spinor bundle, so I'd like to know more about this.